# CSS positioning problems with slideshow

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, css-position

I have this code:

```css
#gallery {
    color: #3d4148;
    margin: 24px 0 48px 0;
}

.gallery-slideshow {
    padding-bottom: 48px;
}

.gallery-buttons {
    width: 60px;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: #f1bf06;
    -webkit-transform: skew(18deg);
       -moz-transform: skew(18deg);
         -o-transform: skew(18deg);
}

.gallery-buttons p {
    color: #f9f8f8;
    font-family: 'permiansanstypefacebold', Arial, sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding-top: 8px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
                <h1 id="gallery" class="text-center">Gallery</h1>
                <div class="cycle-slideshow gallery-slideshow" data-cycle-center-horz=true data-cycle-prev="#prev" data-cycle-next="#next">
                    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/900/500/city" alt="" class="img-responsive">
                    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/900/500/abstract" alt="" class="img-responsive">
                    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/900/500/city" alt="" class="img-responsive">
                    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/900/500/people" alt="" class="img-responsive">
                </div> <!-- end cycle slideshow --> 
                
                <!-- SLIDESHOW CONTROLS -->
                <div class="gallery-buttons" id="prev"><p class="text-center">Prev</p></div>
                <div class="gallery-buttons" id="next"><p class="text-center">Next</p></div> 
            </div>
        </div> <!-- end row --> 
    </div> <!-- end container --> 
</div> <!-- end gallery -->
```

What I want is to get those two divs with the class of gallery-buttons to move up and overlap on top of the images in the slideshow. As you can see I am using bootstrap and cycle2.js. I tried all kinds of possible combination with the position attribute but i can't get it to work. Maybe you could help me.

Comment: Maybe some sort of layout is preventing the overlapping

Comment: may be a codepen would give great idea!

Comment: Is this is what you are expecting? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WrLRev

Answer (score 0):

It seems if you add `position:relative;` and `z-index:999;` to your `.gallery-buttons` it seems to put them on top.

```
.gallery-buttons {
    width: 60px;
    height: 40px;
    transform: skew(18deg); /*I would also add the standard transform*/
    -webkit-transform: skew(18deg);
    -moz-transform: skew(18deg);
    -o-transform: skew(18deg);
    background-color: #f1bf06;
    /*add these*/
    position:relative;
    z-index:999;
}
```

That just puts them on top. Outside of that I don't know how you want them positioned.

See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m4osqx73/)

**UPDATE**

To position how you want you could set the `left`, `right`, and `top` properties accordingly.

```
#prev{
   left: -25px;
}

#next{
    position: absolute;
    top: 400px;
    right: -15px;
}
```

See this updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m4osqx73/1/)

Comment: Hey @zgood. I added what you told me but i didn't quite get the result i needed and I'll let you see why. Check out the next screenshot maybe you get a better idea of what i want to achieve. http://i.imgur.com/kI5vhts.png

Comment: Thank you very much I got the result I wanted. I was writing in CSS    .gallery-buttons #prev instead of    #prev